# Displaying real-time text in Tkinter after Button command calls function?

Tags: python, text, tkinter, real-time

I am trying to display real-time text in Tkinter after a Button command calls a function.  The function should display a "timestamp" when PycURL receives "HTTP/1.1 200 OK".  The function POSTs energy data to a server every 2 minutes.

Pseudocode, a basic example, and/or general discussion should get me headed in the right direction.  I have got the energy data POSTing OK.  Now I need to get the GUI working.

Thanks - Brad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer in the book "Programming Python" by Mark Lutz.  The following code is adapted from the book using info from Threads and Queues!

```
    import thread, Queue, time, random, poster
    from Tkinter import *

    dataQueue = Queue.Queue()

    def status(t):
        try:
            data = dataQueue.get(block=False)
        except Queue.Empty:
            pass
        else:
            t.delete('0', END)
            t.insert('0', '%s\n' % str(data))
        t.after(250, lambda: status(t))

    def makethread():
        thread.start_new_thread(poster.poster, (1,dataQueue))    

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        root = Tk()
        root.geometry("240x45")
        t = Entry(root)
        t.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)
        Button(root, text='Start Epoch Display',
                command=makethread).pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)
        status(t)
        root.mainloop()
```

In another file called poster

```
    import random, time

    def poster(id,que):
        while True:
            delay=random.uniform(0.1, .11)
            time.sleep(delay)
            que.put(' epoch=%f, delay=%f' % (time.time(), delay))
```

This worked.

Answer (score 0):

How are you trying to display real-time text in Tkinter after a button calls a function? What I get so far is, user presses button, function starts and every two minutes posts some data  to a server, and tries to display some text somewhere after each post, but has a problem?

How does it try to display the text, and what's the problem?

(I dont know PycURL, so apologies if that would make everything clear)

Comment: Matt- I want to display text while the function is running.  The function POSTs energy data and should run for years, or as long as the hardware works.   I have been able to display text after the function ends BUT that defeats the real-time status update.

Comment: I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048082 but I don't think queues will handle the real-time nature of this problem.  I also found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588141 but @msw writes that he knows NO known solution.